# Rellenar string en c#

Tags: c#

Buen día, tengo un *richTextBox* con una longitud de caracteres de 260, ahora quiero repartir esos 260 caracteres en 5 variables de tipo *string* dejando en cada una 52 caracteres.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Jose , Cuéntanos que has intentado hasta ahora? .  Podría ayudarte leer https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede realizar con Substring.

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
string myText = myRichTextBox.Text;

string part1 = myText.Substring(0, 52);
string part2 = myText.Substring(51, 52);
string part3 = myText.Substring(103, 52);
string part4 = myText.Substring(155, 52);
string part5 = myText.Substring(207, 52);
```